# How do I make a Date Select component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a component that consists of a `<select>` that will contain options that are months and their values are their numerical dates (eg: Jan = 1, Feb = 2, etc.), and the day and year are controlled with regular number inputs. All of this will return a date format like `"9/26/2019"

So far I'm able to do that with selecting the month and returning something like `"12"`, but I'm not sure how to handle the day and year.

I'm also using a library named [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) to get the current day using `DateTime.local().toLocaleString()` in hopes to have a default value passed in to these inputs, but I'm also not sure on how to achieve that.

so far, this is what I have:

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-shaw-qpc9r

My question is: is there a method to completely handle all of these at once and output a format like `MM/dd/yyyy`? Or should I stick to having 3 completely different inputs that will control each field? Or is there a way I could leverage Luxon to return the date format I need?

Comment: couple of basic errors ... the in the month control, you have `<select onChange={this.handleChange}>` which should be `<select onChange={this.handleSelectChange}>` ... and the output you are doing `<div>date: {this.state.month}</div>` so of course it only displays the month

Comment: try `<div>date: {new Date(this.state.year, this.state.month - 1, this.state.day).toLocaleDateString('en-gb', { month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year:'numeric'})}</div>` - use `en-US` if you want the quaint american date format

Comment: `output a format like MM/dd/yyyy` ... yet the code suggests `25/09/2019' ... there is no 25th month

Comment: create standard select boxes 1-31, 1-12, 1970-2200 or so, and perform validation on change.